# Setup AngularJS 2 Project using `jspm`

Tags: angularjs, jspm

I'm trying to setup AngularJS 2 project using `jspm`, firstly I had tried to setup by following instruction on the angular.io, it's working just fine

So I'm trying to setup another same project but using `jspm` I'm having error about "**ZoneSpec required**", I had tried to google but I have found nothing so far, so please guide me what to do

#### angular.io Version

*app/index.ts*

```
import { bootstrap }    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { AppComponent } from './components/App';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS 2</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.11/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.8.9/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.11/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.11/angular2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
            packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'ts' } }
        });

        System.import('app/index');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>AngularJS 2</h3>
    <hr>
    <test-app>Loading ...</test-app>
</body>
</html>
```

#### `jspm` Version

*Terminal*

```
jspm install angular2 reflect-metada zone.js
```

*app/index.ts*

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { bootstrap }    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { AppComponent } from './components/App';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS 2</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
            packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'ts' } }
        });

        System.import('app/index');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>AngularJS 2</h3>
    <hr>
    <test-app>Loading ...</test-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/lib/zone.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7660

The following tip fixed it for me: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7660#issuecomment-198624392

Add this in your main class (just under `import 'zone.js';`) :

`import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';`